# How to restrict submit action on JSP based on a user role?

Tags: java, jsp, security, tomcat, servlets

I have a **some.jsp** There is an action button, for example **delete**. I have users and their roles. Tomcat 8 provides security. Let's say user made some actions and clicked the button **send** 
The **url** with parameters goes to servlet. Let's take an example of servlet mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.myServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/action1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>administrators</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>action1</web-resource-name>
        <description>action1</description>
        <url-pattern>/action1</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>allowed for administrator</description>
        <role-name>administratorRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Based on above all that comes with `<url-pattern>/action1</url-pattern>` is allowed only for administrator. 
But I want to restrict only **delete** button. Everything else on that **some.jsp** shall be allowed for other users. How to implement it?

JSP part:

```
<form name="frm" action="action1">
    <input type="hidden" name="prm1" value="${prm1}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="prm2" value="${prm2}"/>
    <input id="btnid" type="submit" value="send" name="btn"/>
</form>

<form name="frm" action="action1">
    <input type="hidden" name="prm1" value="${prm1}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="prm2" value="${prm2}"/>
    <input id="btnid" type="submit" value="delete" name="btn"/> 
</form>
```

Servlet part:

```
String actionType=request.getParameter("btn");
if(actionType.equals("send")) doSend();
if(actionType.equals("delete")) doDel();
```

The expected outcome:

- URL like: http://localhost:8084/action1?prm1=111&prm2=221&btn=send is OK to perform by anyone.
- URL like: http://localhost:8084/action1?prm1=111&prm2=221&btn=delete is OK to perform only for administrators.

Comment: maybe its better to create two different actions like `deleteAction` and `sendAction` and restrict `deleteAction` by user role

Comment: hm...not sure. Why? Because the example above is simplified. In reality **delete** exists in many more other *.jsp But everywhere **delete**  shall be allowed only for admins. That is why I am looking the way to deny by **delete** pattern.

Comment: So I guess you should handle it in your servlet. Something like this may help you: `if(actionType.equals("delete") && request.isUserInRole("administratorRole")) doDel();`

Comment: No way to play with URL patterns? As I've read those are quite limitied, do not support regular expression for instance. Or did I miss smth.?

Comment: You can not write regex and as you said the pattern is quite limited